# How to update openssl 1.0.1g to 1.0.1h on xampp?

Tags: openssl, xampp

I have an XAMPP server with OpenSSL 1.0.1g. I have been told by the Networking and Security department of my company to upgrade the openssl to 1.0.1h before they shut down my port. I'm using XAMPP for basic database and web server for my department. How do I can I upgrade it to the new version. Xampp hasn't released a new version yet. I downloaded the new version from https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: I figured it out. I downloaded the wrong file. The files for windows should be downloaded from http://franz.com/ftp/pub/openssl/windows/readme.txt

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.